# Extra config in IHostingStartup not possible?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

Using the new WebApplication in `Program.cs`, and adding some extra config to the builder:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("extra_appsettings.json");
var app = builder.Build();
```

I'd think that the config would be available in IHostingStartup implementations, e.g.

```cs
public void Configure(IWebHostBuilder builder) => builder
   .ConfigureServices((context, services) => {
context.Configuration.GetConnectionString("connectionStringFromOtherFile")
```

Anyone have a solution to this? When debugging it actually seems that all the `IHostingStartup` implementations are being called directly from `CreateBuilder()` before we have a chance to `.AddJsonFile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do below to make the settings from the `extra_appsettings.json` file (being loaded from the web application) available to an `IHostingStartup` implementation in an other assembly.

##### In the web application project

Don't load that `extra_appsettings.json` file from `Program.cs`, so remove below line.

```
builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("extra_appsettings.json");
```

Instead, add an `IHostingStartup` implementation to the web application project itself and make that one load the `extra_appsettings.json` file. Also set an `HostingStartupAttribute`.

```
[assembly: HostingStartup(typeof(MyWebApp.HostStartUp))]

namespace MyWebApp;

public class HostStartUp : IHostingStartup
{
    public void Configure(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        => builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration(
                (context, configurationBuilder) => configurationBuilder.AddJsonFile("extra_appsettings.json")
            );
}
```

##### In the class library project

Add an `IHostingStartup` implementation with matching `HostingStartupAttribute` (like the one you already have).

```
[assembly: HostingStartup(typeof(MyClassLibrary.HostStartUp))]

namespace MyClassLibrary;

public class HostStartUp : IHostingStartup
{
    public void Configure(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        => builder.ConfigureServices((ctx, services) =>
        {
            var cns = ctx.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
            // ...
        });
}
```

##### Configure the loading of the `IHostingStartup` implementations

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/platform-specific-configuration#specify-the-hosting-startup-assembly) shows that one way to do this is by setting the `ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES` environment variable. Note that the one in the web application does not  need to be part of this configuration; it runs automatically as the first one in line.

Order matters if you have more than one assembly with a `IHostingStartup`. The documentation mentions that the order is guaranteed.

> When multiple hosting startup assembles are present, their `Configure` methods are executed in the order that the assemblies are listed.

For above setup, the environment variables look like below.

From the `launchSettings.json` file.

```
"environmentVariables": {
  "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
  "ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES": "MyClassLibrary"
}
```

---

Now the connection string will be available when making below call from within the `IModuleStartup` implementation in that other assembly.

```
var cns = ctx.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
```